# How to sum up object properties with reduce and dynamic keys?

Tags: typescript

Need to create a method a method that takes array of objects and keys then sums up by the passed keys, attempts so far have been unsuccessful( this is pseudo code):

```
const calculateTotals = <T extends object, K extends keyof T>(items: T[], ...keys : K[]) => {
  let result;
      if (keys.length)
      {
          //if I needed to sum up ALL the properties this would suffice, how to plug-in passed keys here?  
          result = items.reduce((r, item) => (Object.entries(item).forEach(([key, value]) => r[key] = (r[key] || 0) + value), r), {});
    
      }
      return result;
}
```

Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few changes you can make to implement your function:

1. Use `keys.forEach` instead of `Object.entries`
2. Don't use `reduce` *and* modify the accumulator. `forEach` works best here.
3. Change the type to have either `T` or `K` generic, but not both. Typescript struggles to maintain the relationship between two type variables.

```js
const calculateTotals = <K extends PropertyKey>(items: Record<K, number>[], ...keys: K[]) => {
  let totals: Partial<Record<K, number>> = {};
  items.forEach((r) =>
    keys.forEach((key) =>
      totals[key] = (totals[key] ?? 0) + r[key]))
  return totals;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for replying! The only issue I have is that `K extends PropertyKey` is too broad, and TS doesn't error when using keys that do not exist on a type, so type safety is off like mine does

Comment: Another issue seems to be I am not trying to sum up all the properties, just a few on a type. So this should work: `calculateTotals([{a: 12, b: 13, c: 2}, {a: 14, b: 15, c: 3}, {a: 14, b: 15, c: 3}], 'c')`, but it errors out

Comment: This is working, however `calculateTotals([{a: 12, b: 13, c: 2}, {a: 14, b: 15, c: 3}, {a: 14, b: 15, c: 3}],  'a', 'b', 'c')` but it's not my use case.

Comment: ① "TS doesn't error when using keys that do not exist on a type" I can't reproduce that; can you demonstrate with a url or something? ② About errors for extra properties: you can take [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mLA3bW)... but are you *really* going to be passing object *literals* in there?  Not sure why you'd need to do that.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for chiming in. Could no longer recreate that either, so nvm. As far as extra properties couldn't make his version work if any props are non-numeric [here](https://shorturl.at/vL247), but yours fixes that, thanks!